# Are hundreds/thousands of tcp sockets reasonable with memcached?

Tags: memcached, merb, connection, persistent

I'm using Merb::Cache for storing txt/xml and have noticed that the longer I leave my merbs running the larger the amount of open tcp sockets I have open -- I believe this is causing some major performance problems.

```
lsof | grep 11211 | wc -l
494
```

```
merb      27206       root   71u     IPv4   13759908                 TCP localhost.localdomain:59756->localhost.localdomain:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
merb      27206       root   72u     IPv4   13759969                 TCP localhost.localdomain:59779->localhost.localdomain:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
merb      27206       root   73u     IPv4   13760039                 TCP localhost.localdomain:59805->localhost.localdomain:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
merb      27206       root   74u     IPv4   13760052                 TCP localhost.localdomain:59810->localhost.localdomain:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
merb      27206       root   75u     IPv4   13760135                 TCP localhost.localdomain:59841->localhost.localdomain:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
merb      27206       root   76u     IPv4   13760823                 TCP localhost.localdomain:59866->localhost.localdomain:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
merb      27206       root   77u     IPv4   13760951                 TCP localhost.localdomain:52095->localhost.localdomain:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
```

etc...

my relevant code is :

```
    if !exists?(:memcached) then
      register(:memcached, Merb::Cache::MemcachedStore, :namespace => 'mynamespace', :servers => ['127.0.0.1:11211'])
    end
```

&&

```
    when :xml
      unless @hand_xml = Merb::Cache[:memcached].read("/hands/#{@hand.id}.xml")
        @hand_xml = display(@hand)
        Merb::Cache[:memcached].write("/hands/#{@hand.id}.xml", @hand_xml)
      end
      return @hand_xml
```

is this code straight out wrong or am I using the wrong version of memcache??

I have memcached 1.2.8
and have the following:

libmemcached-0.25.14.tar.gz
memcached-0.13.gem

this is kind of driving me crazy..

Comment: I'm pretty damn sure that the answer to this question is a big fat no since there are hard limits on the number of sockets you can have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k I figured out some stuff..

1) it CAN be reasonable to have hundreds/thousands of sockets connected to memcached assuming you are using a library that utilizes epoll or something else -- however, if you are using ruby like me I'm not aware of a lib that utilizes something else than select() or poll() -- therefore this strikes this question/want out immediately

2) if you are like me you only have 1 memcached server running right now and a couple of mongrels/thins running around taking care of requests..therefore your memcache connections should prob. be no more than the number of mongrels/thins you have running (assuming you only caching 1 or two sets of things) -- which was my case

here's the fix:

setup memcache through memcached gem rather than merb::cache (which actually wraps whatever memcache lib you are using

```
MMCACHE = Memcached.new("localhost:11211")
```

get/set your values:

```
  @cache = MMCACHE.clone
  begin
    @hand_xml = @cache.get("/hands/#{@hand.id}.xml")
  rescue
    @hand_xml = display(@hand)
    @cache.set("/hands/#{@hand.id}.xml", @hand_xml)
  end
  @cache.quit
```

sit back and drink a cold one cause now when you do this:

```
lsof | grep 11211 | wc -l
```

you see something like 2 or 3 instead of 2036!

props to reef for cluing me in that it's not uncommon for memcache connections to be persistent to begin with

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to help, but I need to tell a story to do that. Here it is.

Once upon a time there was a cluster of 10 apache(ssl) servers configured to have exactly 100 threads each. There also was a cluster of 10 memcached servers (on the same boxes), and they all *seemed* to live peacefully. Both apache's and memcached's were guarded by the evil **monit daemon.**

Then the King installed a 11th apache(ssl) server and memcached's started to restart randomly every few hours! The King started investigating and what did he found? There was a bug in the php memcache module documentation that said that the default constructor of memcache connection object is **not** persistent, but apparently it was. What happened was that every php thread (and there were like 1000 of them), opened a connection to every memcached in the pool when he needed one, and it held it. There were 10*100 connections to every memcached server and it was fine, but with 11 servers it was 1100 and as 1024<1100. Maximum number of open sockets for memcached was 1024. When all the sockets were taken, the monit daemon couldn't connect, so he restarted the memcached.

Every story has to have a moral. So, what did the King do with all of this? He disabled the persistent connections and they all lived happily ever after, with number of connections on the cluster peaking at 5 (five). Those servers were serving hudge amount of data, so We couldn't have 1000 spare sockets and it was cheaper to negotiate the memcache connection on every request.

I am sorry but I don't know ruby, it looks like You had an awful amount of threads or You are caching it wrong.

Good luck!

Comment: well, I think merb::cache is a 2-fold problem -- I only have 1 memcached server running right now and we have 5 merbs (handling 1 connection each, afaik) -- it's persistent for sure but I think it's opening more than it should to begin with... for instance we should only have something like 5 threads max right??